# PHP check if 5min + of time and date

Tags: php

I'm working on a chat / activity system. My site currently logs all activity being page, button submission and if a message is sent its added to a table called activity. With a time stamp and date in format: `12:44:06 (time) 2016-10-19 (date)`
I need to check if there is no activity for a user after 5 minutes.

Therefore I can determine if the user is online or not online. Each activity row has a `u_id (user id)`
I would prefer it was PHP based. I just need a basic php function. So I have $time $date and to check if 5 minuets has passed from that set $time $date value

Comment: better to do in mysql

Comment: @SureshKamrushi Why do you say that? There's no mention in the original question that the user is using mysql.

Comment: I would prefer it was PHP based. I just need a basic php function. So I have $time $date and to check if 5 minuets has passed from that set $time $date value

Comment: Note that this site prefers questions that show what you've tried already rather than simply asking how to do something. This explains the down-vote you've been given (for the record though, it wasn't me).

Comment: Agree to what @Simba said, although maybe this kind of cases could be exceptions to the rule. He's just asking something basic that he doesn't know how to do, so it's probable that he can't show us anything. (Considering that php date handling sucks bad and it's totally antiintuitive..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using OOP php, you could do that this way:

```
$last = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourDate.' '.$yourTime);
$now = new Datetime('now');

$minutes = abs( $last->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp() ) / 60;
```

Then check if it's bigger than 5 and do stuff.

You can also install Carbon, which is an extension of the DateTime class and it makes your life easier when handling dates in php.

Check here: http://carbon.nesbot.com/

Then you could do it this way:

```
$then = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $yourDate.' '.$yourTime);

if($then->addMinutes(5)->isPast()) {
    // stuff
}
```

Way cleaner.

Comment: Yes. Definitely use Carbon. Makes things almost ridiculously simple.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using mysql like below:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, datatime_col, now())
```

With above query you will get the difference in minutes, which you can compare as it is greater than 5 minutes or not.